# Is it possible to show network type in wingpanel?

Tags: wingpanel

I found some network type icons (4G, 3G, H, E, G):

[image]

Is it somehow possible to display the current network type in wingpanel?

Comment: That sounds like an awesome and easy to implement feature! I'd love to report that as a blueprint, but unfortunately, it looks like [Wingpanel Network Indicator's blueprints are not working at the moment](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-network).

Comment: as elementary tracks feature request as bug reports, I just filed a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel-indicator-network/+bug/1480261

Comment: Voting to close since this is a feature request and you've filed an issue in the appropriate place :)